# Problems with the two parameter format function in boost::regex_replace

Tags: c++, regex, templates, boost-regex

I am having problems with the format function in `boost::regex_replace`.  I can call the one parameter version of it, but not the two parameter:

```
e = "(^|>)([^<>]+)";
h_str = regex_replace(h_str, e, repl_quot, boost::match_default);
```

Where `repl_quot` is defined as

```
std::string const &repl_quot(boost::smatch const &what) {
    boost::regex e("\"");
    std::string  repl("&#34;");
    static std::string;
    str = regex_replace(what[0].str(), e, repl, boost::match_default);
    return str;
}
```

The above works, but I don't really want to use that static variable, so I tried what I thought was an acceptable two parameter alternate version:

```
std::string const &repl_quot2(boost::smatch const &what, std::string &out) {
    boost::regex e("\"");
    std::string  repl("&#34;");
    out = regex_replace(what[0].str(), e, repl, boost::match_default);
    return out;
}
```

But regex_replace won't accept this (a convoluted compiler error).  I am trying to use the two parameter version based on the following from the `Boost::Regex` documentation:

> template  basic_string
>   regex_replace(const
>   basic_string& s,
>                                     const basic_regex& e,
>                                     Formatter fmt,
>                                     match_flag_type flags =
>   match_default);
>
> Requires The type Formatter must be
>   either ... a unary, binary or ternary functor that
>   computes the replacement string from a
>   function call: either fmt(what) which
>   must return a container of char_type's
>   to be used as the replacement text, or
>   either fmt(what, out) or fmt(what,
>   out, flags), both of which write the
>   replacement text to *out, and then
>   return the new OutputIterator
>   position. In each case what is the
>   match_results object that represents
>   the match found.

There have been repeated requests for the compiler error message, so here it is (be careful what you ask for):

> c:\boost\boost\regex\v4\regex_format.hpp In member function `OutputIter boost::re_detail::format_functor_container::operator()(const Match&, OutputIter, boost::regex_constants::match_flag_type, const Traits&) [with OutputIter = boost::re_detail::string_out_iterator, std::allocator > >, Container = const std::string&(*)(const boost::smatch&, std::string&), Match = boost::match_results<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator, std::allocator > >, std::allocator, std::allocator > > > > >, Traits = boost::regex_traits_wrapper > >]':
>
> 356 c:\boost\boost\regex\v4\match_results.hpp   instantiated from `OutputIterator boost::match_results::format(OutputIterator, Functor, boost::regex_constants::match_flag_type, const RegexT&) const [with OutputIterator = boost::re_detail::string_out_iterator, std::allocator > >, Functor = const std::string&(*)(const boost::smatch&, std::string&), RegexT = boost::basic_regex > >, BidiIterator = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator, std::allocator > >, Allocator = std::allocator, std::allocator > > > >]'
>
> 60 c:\boost\boost\regex\v4\regex_replace.hpp   instantiated from `OutputIterator boost::regex_replace(OutputIterator, BidirectionalIterator, BidirectionalIterator, const boost::basic_regex&, Formatter, boost::regex_constants::match_flag_type) [with OutputIterator = boost::re_detail::string_out_iterator, std::allocator > >, BidirectionalIterator = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator, std::allocator > >, traits = boost::regex_traits >, charT = char, Formatter = const std::string&(*)(const boost::smatch&, std::string&)]'
>
> 80 c:\boost\boost\regex\v4\regex_replace.hpp   instantiated from `std::basic_string, std::allocator<_T2> > boost::regex_replace(const std::basic_string, std::allocator<_T2> >&, const boost::basic_regex&, Formatter, boost::regex_constants::match_flag_type) [with traits = boost::regex_traits >, charT = char, Formatter = const std::string&(*)(const boost::smatch&, std::string&)]'
>
> 327 C:\Dev-Cpp\Examples\wordrad\xhtml_open.cpp   instantiated from here
>
> 1064 c:\boost\boost\regex\v4\regex_format.hpp request for member `begin' in`((boost::re_detail::format_functor_container, std::allocator > >, std::allocator, std::allocator > > > > >, boost::regex_traits_wrapper > > >*)this)->boost::re_detail::format_functor_container, std::allocator > >, std::allocator, std::allocator > > > > >, boost::regex_traits_wrapper > > >::func', which is of non-class type `const std::string&(* const)(const boost::smatch&, std::string&)'
>
> 1064 c:\boost\boost\regex\v4\regex_format.hpp request for member `end' in`((boost::re_detail::format_functor_container, std::allocator > >, std::allocator, std::allocator > > > > >, boost::regex_traits_wrapper > > >*)this)->boost::re_detail::format_functor_container, std::allocator > >, std::allocator, std::allocator > > > > >, boost::regex_traits_wrapper > > >::func', which is of non-class type `const std::string&(* const)(const boost::smatch&, std::string&)'

Comment: You should post the error you're getting.

Comment: Its absurdly long.  I predict you wouldn't  make heads or tails of it. Its template related or something. The problem is with what regex-replace is expecting as a signature for the fmt parameter, petaining to templates or whatever.  THe error message is indecipherable.

Comment: 1064 c:\boost\boost\regex\v4\regex_format.hpp request for member `end' in `((boost::re_detail::format_functor_container<const std::string&(*)(const boost::smatch&, std::string&), boost::match_results<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<const char*, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >, std::allocator<boost::sub_match<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<const char*, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > > > >, boost::regex_traits_wrapper<boost::regex_traits<char, boost::cpp_regex_traits<char> > > >*)this)->boost::re_detail::format_fu...

Comment: I think there is something missing in the line `static std::string;`, or the semicolon must be removed there. And I don't think `str` needs to be static in that example. Can you post the whole error message in the question, as these comments are not long enough for the complete error message.

Comment: Wimmel - the version with static std::string in it is the one that's working.  Even the other version repl_quot2 actually compiles.  The compiler error occurs if I pass repl_quot2 as a parameter to regex_replace (insead of repl_quot)  because the parameters and return value of regex_quot2 don't conform to what regex_replace is expecting, and I don't know what it wants.  You can see from the documentation excerpt that a function of one two or three parameters is acceptable. It also says that with two parameters, you write the replacement text to *out and return the new "OutputIterator" pos...

Comment: To be honest, I don't know what it means by OutputIterator, so that's part of the problem.  There is a more detailed example at http://boost-sandbox.sourceforge.net/libs/xpressive/doc/html/boost_xpressive/user_s_guide/string_substitutions.html,  but it concerns Boost::xpressive, as opposed to Boost::regex, but the two are supposed to be closely related.  But my code is following what is described on that page for Boost::xpressive, because that is the only doc I've found providing detailed examples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK here's how I had to write repl_quot2:

```
struct formatter
{       
  template<typename Out>
  Out operator()(boost::smatch const &what, Out out) const {
    boost::regex e("\"");    
    std::string  repl("&#34;");
    std::string str
      = regex_replace(what[0].str(), e, repl, boost::match_default);
    out = std::copy(str.begin(), str.end(), out);
    return out;
  }

};
```

And then when invoking it from regex_replace:

```
  e = "(^|>)[^<>]+";
  formatter repl_quot2;
  h_str = regex_replace(h_str, e, repl_quot2, boost::match_default);
```

This corresponds to the documentation at http://boost-sandbox.sourceforge.net/libs/xpressive/doc/html/boost_xpressive/user_s_guide/string_substitutions.html.

What puzzles me at the moment is that it requires a functor (a class with the () operator) as opposed to a function if the two parameter version is called, but did not require a functor for the one parameter versions (repl_quot in the OP).  Anyway, haven't gotten the new two parm version to work as a straight function.  But the main problem was `out` which I had to pass and return as a template parameter as shown, as opposed to making it std::string as in the OP.  Its supposed to be an OutputIterator -still don't know what that is actually.

Incidentally, all this regex does is replace double quotes with the html entity version, 
\&#34; in any text in html not part of a tag.

Also, the reason I wanted to replace my original function repl_quot is that I had to store the return value in a static local variable in repl_quot.  It doesn't work to just return a normal local variable, because it can be deallocated before it can even be used (and caused crashes).  repl_quot was working - my problem with the static is that it isn't thread safe, and didn't know if Boost::RegEx was multithreading. I think I compiled it as multithreading, but the static var didn't seem to cause problems.  But with repl_quot2 I write the return value to an output parameter.